# Converting Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext to System.Web.HttpContext

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

My team is working on a new project that is built on the ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET Framework) template. For legacy reasons we have another project that was build upon `System.Web` and directly accesses `HttpContext` via `HttpContext.Current`. Since our new project uses `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext` we would like to know if its possible to convert the `HttpContext` to the older `System.Web.HttpContext`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

'Legacy' ASP.NET and ASP.NET Core don't play well together. In fact, I'd be surprised if they do at all. Their nature and characteristics are very different. Mocking the `HttpContext` in the legacy ASP.NET is pretty difficult. And even if you could, it's gonna be a hell of a job to set it correctly in the `HttpContext.Current` without being bitten by multi-threading issues.

My suggestion is to migrate the legacy application or expose the legacy functionality via a web API and use that to communicate between the two applications.